# Weights in Convolutional network?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am currently following the TensorFlow's [Multilayer Convolutional Network](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/mnist/pros/index.html#build-a-multilayer-convolutional-network) tutorial.

In various layers weight is initialised as followed :

- First Convolutional Layer:

  ```
  W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])
  ```
- Second Convolutional Layer:

  ```
  W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
  ```
- Densely Connected Layer:

  ```
  W_fc1 = weight_variable([7 * 7 * 64, 1024])
  ```
- Readout Layer:

  ```
  W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 10])
  ```

So I am having doubts in **how is the shape of the above weight variables known to us ?**

**Is their any math used to find the shape for them ?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer is explained on the same page:

> The convolutional will compute 32 features for each 5x5 patch. Its
>   weight tensor will have a shape of [5, 5, 1, 32]

There is no involved math par say, but these terms need explanation

1. The size of convolution kernel is `5X5`. That means there is a `5X5` matrix that is *convolved* with an input image by moving it around the image. Check [this link](http://setosa.io/ev/image-kernels/) for an explanation of how a small `5X5` matrix moves over a `28X28` image and multiplies different cells of the image matrix with itself. This gives us first two dimentsions of `[5, 5, 1, 32]`
2. The size of input channels is `1`. These are BW images, hence one input channel. Most colored images have 3 channels, so expect a `3` in some other convolution networks working on images. Indeed, for the second layer, `W_conv2`, the number of input channels is `32`, same as number of output channels of layer 1.
3. The last dimension of the weight matrix is perhaps hardest to visualize. Imagine your `5X5` matrix, and replicate it 32 times!. Each of these 32 things are called `channels`. To complete the discussion, each of these 32 `5X5` matrices are initialized with random weights and trained independently during forward/back propagation of the network. More channels learn different aspects of the image and hence give extra power to your network.

If you summarize these 3 points, you get desired dimensions of layer 1. Subsequent layers are an extension - First two dimensions are kernel sizes (5X5) in this case. Third dimension is equal to size of input channel, which is equal to size of output channel of previous layer. (32, since we declared 32 output channels  of layer 1). Final dimension is the size of output channel of current layer (64, even lager for second layer!. Again, keeping a large number of independent 5X5 kernels helps!).

Finally, last two layers: Final dense layer is the only thing that involves some calculation:

1. For each convolution layer, final size = initial size
2. For pooling layer of size kXk, final size = initial size / k

So,

1. For conv1, size remains `28 X 28`
2. pool1 reduces size to `14 X 14`
3. For conv2, size remains `14 X 14`
4. pool2 reduces size to `7 X 7`

And ofcourse, we have `64` channels due to conv2 - pooling doesn't affect them. Hence, we get a final dense input of `7X7X64`. We then create fully connected `1024` hidden layers and add `10` output classes for `10` digits.

Comment: Thanks for brilliant explanation. You mentioned `32 things are called channels`; I am still a bit confused with this, how would we decide it must be 32 and not 20 (like in this [example](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap6.html#convolutional_neural_networks_in_practice)).

Comment: There's no fixed formula for deciding that number. Each channel creates an abstract intermediate representation of the image (one of edges, other for contrast maybe) - more is usually better, too many channels make it slow to learn and cause overfitting

Comment: Okay, so same will go for 1024 in Densely Connected Layer ?

Comment: Yes. Usually more is merrier, but too many are hard to train and overfit